# Закрыть модальное окно после отправки?

Tags: javascript

```js
function showModalWin() {

var darkLayer = document.createElement('div');
        darkLayer.id = 'shadow'; 
        document.body.appendChild(darkLayer); 
        var modalWin = document.getElementById('feedback-form'); 
        modalWin.style.display = 'block'; 
        darkLayer.onclick = function () {  
        darkLayer.parentNode.removeChild(darkLayer); 
                modalWin.style.display = 'none'; 
                return false;
        };
}

document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(), f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "http://localhost/views/product/contact.php", true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.send("nameFF=" + f.nameFF.value + "&contactFF=" + f.contactFF.value + "&phoneFF=" + f.productFF.value + "&productFF=" + f.phoneFF.value + "&messageFF=" + f.messageFF.value);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText + ', Ваше сообщение получено.\nНаши специалисты ответят Вам в течении 2-х дней.\nБлагодарим за интерес к нашей фирме!');    
      f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value'); 
      f.messageFF.value='';
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#feedback-form {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 2%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    font: 16px/30px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    z-index:2;
    top: 9%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*display: none;*/
    position: fixed;

}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="feedback-form" >
    Выбран продукт:
    <input type="text" name="productFF" required value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" readonly>
    Как к Вам обращаться:
    <input type="text" name="nameFF" required placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество" x-autocompletetype="name" >
    Email для связи:
    <input type="email" name="contactFF" required placeholder="Адрес электронной почты" x-autocompletetype="email">
    Контактный телефон:
    <input type="tel" name="phoneFF" required placeholder="Номер телефона" x-autocompletetype="phone">
    Ваш комментарий:
    <textarea name="messageFF" required rows="5"></textarea>
    <input class="to-cart" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Возможно, вы забыли рассказать, что вам нужно от этого кода…

Comment: как закрыть модальное окно после отправки данных с формы

Comment: `document.getElementById('feedback-form').style.display = "none";`

Comment: Именно! Еще вопрос - как отключить стиль #shadow (затемнение)

Comment: `document.getElementById('shadow').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('shadow'));`